Does anyone know if a lagrangian term of the form $\mathcal{L}=\frac{g}{4}\bar{\psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu \nu}\psi$ has a name?
I am currently working in a problem that involes an interaction lagrangian of the form $\mathcal{L}=\frac{g}{4}\bar{\psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu \nu}\psi$ and i would like to know if it has a name so that i can look for more information about it.
I found one paper that used it but in a different context that I need it.

It is the Pauli moment of your QFT text or WP.

It is the primary application of the Gordon decomposition of the current. (3.209) of J J Sakurai's superb Advanced Quantum Mechanics you should all but know by heart...

This is a Pauli coupling between a fermion and a gauge field. This term gives a contribution to the anomalous magnetic moment and dipole moments of the fermion.
